# PJSip. What class should be used in order to implement sip request?

Tags: sip, voip, pjsip

Now I'm trying to use PJSip in my project. In documentation I can't find any information about what classes I should use in order to implement SIP request (REGISTER, INVITE, BYE, ACK, CANCEL...)

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Call class](http://www.pjsip.org/python/pjsua.htm#Call) has a method `send_request` which can be used to send specific requests to the remote call.

For instance, you can get a `Call` object as a result of a call to the `make_call` method of your [Account object](http://www.pjsip.org/python/pjsua.htm#Account-make_call):

```
call = acc.make_call(dst_uri, cb=my_cb)
call.send_request("INFO")
```

Comment: @Pein I'm glad I could. Cheers!